# Having trouble getting uint value from contract

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm trying to retrieve a public variable from a contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Test_Uint {
    uint public something;

    function Test_Uint() {
        something = 42;
    }
}
```

Note the hard-coded value 42. Here is the test code in truffle:

```
var thing = artifacts.require("./Test_Uint.sol");

contract('Test_Uint', function(accounts) {

  it("should provide access to something", function() {

    thing.deployed().then(function(instance) {

      instance.something.call().then(function(res) {
          console.log(res);
      });    
    });
  });
});
```

I was hoping for 42 or even "42", but it always prints:

```
{ [String: '42'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [ 42 ] }
```

What is the right way to access the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is a `BigNumber` object. You probably want to do:

```
console.log(res.toString())
```

See more on this in [the BigNumber docs](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/).